# Webjob HttpWebResponse timing out

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-webjobs

I have a list of around 1000 applicants. I have to call an API to delete them each individually using the below inside a for loop. When I run this code in a console app it works fine. When I run this code from a scheduled webjob it runs runs for the first 2 then `HttpWebResponse` times out.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url + "/applicants/" + applicants["id"]);
request.Method = "DELETE";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token token=XXX");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if ((int)response.StatusCode == 204)
{
    Console.WriteLine(applicants["id"] + " marked for deletion");
    counter++;
}
```

Is there something on the webjob preventing multiple requests?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632256/httpwebrequest-port-exhaustion

Comment: Are you using .net core 2?

Comment: Thanks looks like i need to do some reading on ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

Comment: If you 're using .net core 2 then use IHttpClientfactory to manage sockets, if you need an example let me know.

Comment: thanks, but nope using .net 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue with:

```
response.Close();
```